# firebase.js (Firebase js API) not recognized in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, firebase, webstorm

I am using (testing) Webstorm 7 EAP for development. I downloaded the
https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js
to be able to have code completion and JSDocs for Firebase.
To my disappointment not only do I not jet the JSDocs (the firebase.js appears to be minified), but webstorm can't even see the Firebase API at all.
When I type:

```
var fbase = new Firebase(...)
```

Webstorms warns "Unresolved type Firebase".
How can I get Webstotm to play with Firebase nicely?
I get a feeling that my problem is due to firebase.js being minified.
Is there somewhere a version of firebase.js that is not minified and with JSDocs? Would help a lot.
BTW Oddly enough, Webstorm 7 can see angularFire.js just fine.
regards
Jared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [unminified version of Firebase for development](http://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase-debug.js). Also, if WS is still fussy you can try a couple different things.

Find the reference to Firebase in your code and click on it, click the light bulb, choose download library:

[image]

Add Firebase-debug to your JS Libs under Project Settings -> JavaScript -> Libraries. You'll have to download the -debug version first, then make sure you've checked it for inclusion in the project:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Works the way I wanted. Thanks for the "Download library" tip. very useful. Do you know what happens if the downloaded library is updated? Will it re-download/overwrite the older version? Will Webstorm notify me when new version of is issued, or do I need to download it manually? Any way thanks a lot for both, the answer and the effort (screenshots:). Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how caching works; I've never noticed any issues so it prob checks at some interval, but apis don't change too frequently either. If you run into issues you can use the js lib approach, which allows you to control versions control updates.

Comment: ic. BTW, where did you find the link to this version of firebase.js? Is it mentioned somewhere on the Firebase official site?

Comment: I saw it in the mailing list :)

Comment: Looks like Firebase doesn't ship a debug.js file for the latest version of the Firebase SDK: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/PuubUKUg_4Y/g5uKSn0CBQAJ